# I have two versions of glib on my system, and I don't know how to remove the old one

Tags: compiling, glib

While trying to compile a program (pygobject), running 
 ./configure
I am told that I don't have glib.  So, I download the tarball and compile and install, no problems.
now when I try to ./configure the package again, I get the following error:

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.24.0... 
*** 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.34.2, but GLIB (2.34.0)
*** was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
*** by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
*** /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
*** required on your system.
*** If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
*** to point to the correct configuration files 
no 
configure: error: maybe you want the pygobject-2-4 branch?
```

Here is the entire prompt: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Gs6MrTWh

Comment: Have you found solution for this issue. please let me know, i'm also stuck with issue. saravana